# How to start a job at precise time?

Tags: cron-jobs

I want to start a recording job at a precise time. As I understand cron only guarantees a job to be started within a minute.

One possible solution is to start the cron job earlier and than wait until the precise time. What other possibilities do I have?

Comment: What accuracy are you looking for... I have a script which will time things to an accuracy of 0.01 of a second ... but of course that depends on the system load....   It uses `date`'s  nanosecond timer... Using seconds can at best give you an average of +/- 0.5 of a second...  But it's unlikely that it matters... I've just put it together as an exercise...

Comment: I need 1/10 of a second. But the solution to start the cron job 2 minutes earlier and than wait e.g in a python script works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way is to put cron job to start it minute earlier and then add timing by your own.

You can also use `at`. At least man page of `at` says that you can use rather exact timing, including seconds. You can test this by adding `at` job that records time, for example shell script running

```
date > ~/at_test
```

If you go with cron route, `date +%s` is your friend.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash
target_time=1298301898
let wait_time=target_time-`date +%s`
if [ $wait_time -gt 0 ]; then
 sleep wait_time
fi
# Execute your code
```

With this approach your next problem is to figure out how to determine target_time. If you always know that you want to start it in the next minute, you can use

```
sleep 2 # Avoid running on xx:59, if cron starts immediately.
let wait_time=60-`date +%M`
sleep wait_time
```

to wait until minute changes.

Comment: Using Olli's idea.. I've put together a script which will countdown, until a specified millisecond time.. It initially polls once per second (for the countdown display), until it is within a couple of seconds of the target time, and then shifts to checking th time every millisecond. Here is the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/570361/ ...*(new link)*

Comment: @fred.bear: That looks... complicated, but on the other hand when you need better accuracy than +-1s it's more difficult.